# React frontend, node backend CORS issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors

I am sending a post request from my React app using the following code.

```
// https://react-app.com

await fetch('https://node-backend-on-aws-lambda-api.com/stage/resource', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    mode: 'cors',
    body: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
})
```

On the server side I have enabled `cors` using the `cors node.js package` like this:

```
// https://node-backend-on-aws-lambda-api.com/stage/resource

var cors = require('cors')
...
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

But when I try to send a post request to my node backend, I still get this response?!

```
Access to fetch at 'https://node-backend-on-aws-lambda-api.com/stage/resource' 
from origin 'https://react-app.com' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the 
resource with CORS disabled.
```

By simply accessing the server url directly from the browser `https://node-backend-on-aws-lambda-api.com/stage/resource`
I see that the correct headers are in place (see image)

---

**This image are the headers when I access the node backend directly**

[image]
[image]

---

**This image are the headers I get from my React app**

[image]

***What more do I need to do?***

Comment: Does your node backend respond correctly to the preflight request (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)?

Comment: I think so, how do I know for sure? Considering that the server header includes `access-control-allow-methods` with the relevant methods, can it not be assumed that the preflight is ok?

Comment: The preflight is an `OPTIONS` request. It might happen that your node backend does not threat OPTIONS requests at all. See the Network tab in your browser's dev tools panel.

Comment: Try adding an `app.options('/stage/resource', cors())` to your express server.

Comment: Hi Andor, I added that line of code but it was still got the CORS error.

Comment: Hey Zoli, I looked, but I am seeing the same thing as the image I sent in the original post. Or what is it that I should be looking for exactly in the Network tab?

Comment: Edited post by adding the image of the headers that I get when accessing my React app.

Comment: You should look for an OPTIONS request above the actual GET request.

Comment: #1 is your cors() config addee at the start? I mean before any other middlewares. #2 In order to add more proofs, try to consume with other terchnology. Here I have a template with jquery https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/6b6f2c0d052253f7b76a35427bdff1b9#file-jquery-ajax-template-1-html. Share us the result

Comment: Hi Zoli, I extended the post by adding an image from the Network tab when sending a GET request to the Node Backend (now the first image in the post), as you can see there is nothing above the actual GET request, is that the issue in our case?

Comment: Hi Richard, I am using AWS Lambda and I have active layers on this Lambda function, do they count as middleware? Excellent point, not sure about the answer though.

Comment: Sorry, I might have mislead you with the GET request. There will be CORS preflight request only when using `fetch` (AJAX request). There will be no preflight request for directly accessing the backend URL from the browser. So you should look for the OPTIONS (preflight) request while executing your React app. I just saw now that you wrote that that's a POST request. Find the OPTIONS request before the POST request.

Comment: u can probably try removing `mode: cors`. I haven't used that for cross site fetches and it worked fine once I use cors package on my node backend.

Comment: AND, importantly, it looks like you are using Lambda + Gateway, you should refer to this to set the relevant cors header. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html instead of using cors package.

Comment: Hello Someone Special, I will try that solution. However there are a few parts of that article that confuse me, for example: `You can still set up the required OPTIONS response headers in API Gateway.` but I can not see anywhere to set up OPTIONs in API Gateway. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Hey Someone Special, I tried following the instructions in the article multiple times, but still got the same CORS error.

Answer (score 2):

As the error said:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested

You should setup CORS's options in server side. Try this:

```
const cors = require('cors');

const corsOptions = {
  origin: (origin, callback) => {
    callback(null, true);
  },
  methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE"],
  allowedHeaders: ["Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Origin", "X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization"],
  credentials: true
};

app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Comment: Hey Ahmad, thank you for the answer, unfortunately that still rendered the same error. I believe as someone previously said it has to do with the code being deployed to AWS Lambda.

Comment: why do you need to use options and use?

Comment: to make this work you need to give an object of ``{ origin: true }`` for the second parameter of the ``callback`` function inside ``origin``. So basically it should look like this: ``callback(null, { origin: true })``

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I combined AWS Lambda function with API Gateway. If there is an error or crash in the Lambda function, the API Gateway will still respond with a HTTP status code 200, but without any of the needed headers. Therefore when testing the service in a production environment crashes and errors in the backend code will give a 200 response with no CORS passing headers.

The issue was resolved was solved by pushing a fix to the backend code, in the lambda function itself.